# Add a geom_vline to the tallest histogram bin in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

How can I add a `geom_vline` on the *tallest bin* of a histogram?

The following is ***not*** what I want, because it goes by `max(x)`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(15)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100,5,2))

df |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=x))+ 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  stat_bin(geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = after_stat(max(x) ) ), binwidth = 1, color = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

But I want the x value that corresponds to `max(y)`.

*Desired Output*

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using e.g. `which.max` you could do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(15)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(100, 5, 2))

df |>
  ggplot(aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1) +
  stat_bin(
    geom = "vline", aes(xintercept = after_stat(x[which.max(count)])),
    binwidth = 1, color = "red"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: would you care answering the equivalent to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47000494/how-to-add-mean-and-mode-to-ggplot-histogram?